# How to convert hash in to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, perl, extjs, hash

```
$VAR1 = {
        'time_stamp' => '06/20/13 09:53',
         'data' => {
             'TOS1' => {
                 '69' => {
                   '65' => {
                       'LINK_STATUS' => 1,
                        'KPIS' => {
                            Aailability' => {
                                   'status' => 'G',
                                     'val' => '100'
                                             },
                            'Completion Time' => {
                                'status' => 'G',                          
                                  'val' => '1'
                                   }
                                      }
                                 }
                           }
                    }
           }
   };
```

I want to convert this hash in to an array. i got this in json and store it in one variable in javascript. i want display this all values in tabular format
 plz suggest me

Comment: Well, (1) What output data structure do you expect? I can't read your mind to tell what “tabular format” you want. (2) What have you tried to achieve that output. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Whence the 'perl' tag?

Answer (score 1):

So what you have there is a deeply-nested object graph. To make an array out of it, you'd probably use `for-in` to loop through the properties of the object at each level and use the values to build up an array. It's not remotely clear from the question what you might want that array to look like, so I can't really help further.

Here's what a `for-in` loop looks like:

```
var key;

for (key in obj) {
    // Here, `key` will have each property name; to get
    // that property's value, use obj[key]
}
```

So for example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
var key;

for (key in obj) {
    console.log(key + "=" + obj[key]);
}
```

...will output

```
a=1
b=2
```

*(the order isn't guaranteed)*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to convert that to an array. In Javascript arrays can only have numerical keys.

You can iterate over the object properties with a `for in`:

```
for (var property in $VAR1) {
    if ($VAR1.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property); // time_stamp
        console.log($VAR1[property]); // 06/20/13 09:53
    }
}
```

Given that you have nested objects, you'd need nested loops to iterate over the nested objects.

Comment: hi MrCode thanks for feedback, can u explain it in brief so, i can use it in my code